# Using Plot and Piecewise to graph a roller coaster

Tags: plotting, piecewise, homework

I am graphing a roller coaster using Piecewise and Plot commands on Mathematica. I have the first 2 Piecewise functions and would like to add a loop to the end of it.
Here is my initial graph:

[image: graph]

This is the command I used for the graph above:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{0, 0 < x < 1}, {-x + 1, 1 < x < 2}, {((x - 4)^2 - 5),
 2 < x < 5}}], {x, -1, 10}]
```

I would like to add a piece (just from x=2 to around x=6) of the following loop to the end of the above graph:

[image: loop]

I used the following command for the above graph:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[x] + x/2, Sin[x]}, {x, 1, 16}]
```

The loop has to be below the x-axis. I might have the wrong function for this graph, since cosine won't go below x=-1.
How would I go about doing this?

Even if it's not a "pretty" loop like the one above, it works. I tried to just add a circle to it, but when I try to graph both the positive and negative functions of a circle, I only get the bottom half.

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{0, 0 < x < 1}, {-x + 1, 1 < x < 2}, {((x - 4)^2 - 5),
 2 < x < 5}, {-4, 5 < x < 6}, {-Sqrt[4 - (x - 8)^2] - 4, 
5 < x < 10}, {Sqrt[4 - (x - 8)^2] - 4, 5 < x < 10}}], {x, -1, 10}]
```

Comment: "below the x-axis" - then you're supposed to shift the $y$-component downward, no?

Comment: You probably should also match the derivatives.

Comment: @bel, in fact, if OP wants a smooth "ride" in his coaster, he should be matching up to the second derivative (i.e. a $C^2$ curve)…

Comment: I don't understand what you guys mean by matching the derivatives.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Given the treatment at `x == 2`, I guess the public is warned about some engineering faults :)

Comment: What we are saying is that the first and second derivatives also have to be (made of) continuous functions, in addition to the curve itself. These are the sorts of things actual roller coaster builders worry about.

Comment: @bel, yes, the customers will be complaining of sore bottoms after the ride… :D

Comment: For example [**this**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w3xWj.png)  is why @Guesswhoitis. wants to match the function, first AND second derivative

Comment: I understand. However, the actual physics of roller coasters are ignored for this assignment. I know if a roller coaster was built like this graph, it would crash. That has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equating function and [first derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_derivative):

```
f1[x_] := {x, ((x - 4)^2 - 5)}
f2[x_] := {c + Cos[x + a] + (x + a)/2, b + Sin[x + a]}

s = {Reduce[ Join[
      Thread[f1[5] == f2[5]], 
            {f1'[5][[2]] == f2'[5][[2]]/(f2'[5][[1]])}], {a, b}, 
             Backsubstitution -> True] /. C[1] -> 0 // ToRules}

kk[n_] := Piecewise[
  {
   {{x, 0}, 0 < x < 1},
   {{x, 1 - x}, 1 < x < 2},
   {f1[x], 2 < x < 5},
   {f2[x] /. s[[n]], x > 5}}, 0]

ParametricPlot[kk[#], {x, 0, 10}] & /@ {1, 2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here you have a nice smooth design equating the function, the [first and second derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_derivative) :)

```
f1[x_] := {x, ((x - 4)^2 - 5)}
f2[x_] := {c + d Cos[ x + a] + ( x + a)/2, b + d Sin[x + a]}
s = {Reduce[
      Join[
       Thread[f1[5] == f2[5]],
       {f1'[5][[2]] == f2'[5][[2]]/(f2'[5][[1]])},
       {f1''[5][[2]] == (f2'[5][[1]] (f2''[5][[2]]) - (f2'[5][[2]]) (f2''[5][[1]]))/
                        (f2'[5][[1]])^3}
       ], Backsubstitution -> True] /. C[1] -> 0 // ToRules};

kk[n_] := Piecewise[
  {
   {{x, 0}, 0 < x < 1},
   {{x, 1 - x}, 1 < x < 2},
   {f1[x], 2 < x < 5},
   {f2[x] /. s[[n]], x > 5}}, 0]

ParametricPlot[kk[2], {x, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You accepted too soon ...